# Single term answer to Alexa Skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

## Background

I'm writing an Alexa Skill and looking to get pieces of information from the user.

The following conversation for example:

```
Alexa: What month were you born at?
User: April
Alexa: Good. And what was your favorite movie?
User: April
```

## The problem

Given the following utterances:

```
GetMonthIntent {month}
GetMovieIntent {movie}
```

Once a user answers `April` for the second time, the `GetMonthIntent` might be triggered.

## What I have tried

Asking the user to specify *which* piece of information is giving by using the following utterances:

```
GetMonthIntent Month {month}
GetMovieIntent Movie {movie}
```

## The question

What is the right way to make Alexa wait for a single term answer based on the current context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no solution.  There is no way to specify the 'context' in which a user reply should be interpreted, so you have to tell the user "what was your favorite movie?  Please say 'my favorite movie is' and then the name of the movie".

Here are two ASK feature requests that I think would address your issue:
https://forums.developer.amazon.com/content/idea/41062/creating-something-to-help-with-more-structured-qu.html
https://forums.developer.amazon.com/content/idea/55525/allow-a-response-to-specify-a-set-of-expected-inte.html

Personally I think this is fairly important so I voted for those, but they are not near the top.

Answer (score 1):

In the same vein as the other answers here, you should take a look at the newest Node.JS library here, which handles state out of the box:
https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs#making-skill-state-management-simpler

You could define:

- State_Launch
- State_Month
- State_Movie

And then return the proper error response if anything other than the GetMovieIntent or GetMonthIntent (etc.) intents are called in the wrong state.

You would have to do data validation on the server side to make sure the "month" is a valid one, and movies are even harder to validate unless you have a list of expected values. That is, if you care to parse them for use beyond repeating back.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem when I created the "Who's on First? Baseball Skit" skill. I handled this by:

1. Create a sequence number for each response given by Alexa
2. Write this number to the "session" in the response.
3. The session is then passed back to your skill by Alexa in the next request.
4. Read the sequence number from the request to know what the previous question was.
5. If a given intent could  be the answer to multiple questions (eg. month and movie in your case) then use the sequence number to determine which it is.

This should give you ideas on how to deal with repeated answers. The session is quite easy to use. Other options include writing the userId and status to a database like DynamoDB, but I find that the session works in most cases.